# how to add a drop down menu with options for an element created with a function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, menu

I have this form created using a function whenever I hit a button (add TP in the image). How do I add the options to it so they appear for the user to select?
The target element is the one with no placeholder in the attached image.

```
        const aim = document.createElement("input");
        aim.setAttribute("type", "select");
        aim.setAttribute("name", "aim");


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FhyZ.jpg
```

Comment: "select" is not a valid type for an input element. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: it says that 'select' is used to create dropdown menus.

Comment: Yes, a <select> element (not an <input> element with a type="select" attribute) is used to create dropdown menus.